# Date data from MySQL to Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, date, highcharts

Really new to Highcharts and PHP. Trying to use date from my SQL database but can get the X-axis to recognise the data as dates.

My PHP request looks like this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ipagemysql.com', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("history") or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eur_weekly")
or die(mysql_error());  


WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $EUR1 [] = $row ['price'];
    $EUR2 [] = $row ['date'];}

    ?>
```

Where "date" is my date column organised as follow:

31.01.2014

31.12.2013

30.11.2013

31.10.2013

30.09.2013

31.08.2013

In my HTML code I use this function that works with the rest of the data but it wont recognise the "dates" as dates data for the x-axis:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'EUR/USD '
        },
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            categories: [<?php echo join($EUR2,',') ?> ],
        }],

        yAxis: [{ 
            labels: {
                 format: '{value} price',
                      style: {
                           color: '#CC33FF',
                            lineWidth: 0.5 
                              }
                       },

                }],

         tooltip: {  },
         series: [{

            name: 'EUR/USD',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'spline',
            marker:{ enabled: false},
            zIndex:1,
            data: [ <?php echo join($EUR1, ',') ?>  ],


        }]


    });
});


    </script>
```

Is there a transformation I should do? Can't find a simple example of dates from MySQL imported into Highcharts..

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Change the data format to yyyy-mm-dd ;)

Comment: Thanks I was able to have it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your dates, to achieve that you can transform time to unix and multiply by 1000 in the php, other solution is parse dates in javascript.

I advice to use json_encode(), which return json in php (then load it by getJSON() in javascript), instead of inject php inside javascript.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into my issue, was able to have it work